# Swipe/sliding tab ionic 2

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular, ionic2

i want to implement sliding/swipe tabs to the ones of [material design spec](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage), how to implement this in ionic2,  Ionic2 have sliding/swipe option?

if "No" any Other jquery plugin available? like [material design spec](https://material.google.com/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage)

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="contacts" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="lab" tabIcon="lab"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="school" tabIcon="school"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab6Root" tabTitle="student" tabIcon="student"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tab7Root" tabTitle="play" tabIcon="play"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
```

file.Ts here my typescript file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
        import {HomePage} from '../home-page/home-page';
        import {AboutPage} from '../about-page/about-page';
        import {ContactPage} from '../contact-page/contact-page';
        import {LabPage} from '../lab-page/lab-page';
        import {SchoolPage} from '../school-page/school-page';
        import {StudentPage} from '../student-page/student-page';
       import {playPage} from '../play-page/play-page';


        @Component({
          templateUrl: 'build/pages/tabs/tabs.html'
        })
        export class TabsPage {
          constructor() {
            // this tells the tabs component which Pages
            // should be each tab's root Page
            this.tab1Root = HomePage;
            this.tab2Root = AboutPage;
            this.tab3Root = ContactPage;
            this.tab4Root = LabPage;
            this.tab5Root = SchoolPage;
            this.tab6Root = StudentPage;
            this.tab7Root = PlayPage;
          }
        }
```

Comment: This feature sounds very difficult to implement but it has been raised to the Ionic team and it is down for being added in the beta 12 release (this may change though). Here is the GitHub feature request https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5101

Comment: thank u for your ans, Any other jquery plugin available?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of sorry

Comment: @sridharan did you solve this issue if you have please place it as an answer

Comment: @Will.Harris is there any solution for this issue i am not able to get an idea how to use it

Comment: @Mohan Gopi, im unsure i've not spent any time using Ionic since last year. It looks like they aren't making it a priority at the minute though but I don't know if there are any workarounds unfortunately

Comment: @Will.Harris https://github.com/SinoThomas/Ionic2-ScrollableTabs this is an example for the scrolable tabs but it is complecated for me to understand is there any way i can achive it in easy steps

Answer (score 0):

So you need to have your [HTML] code in the following way:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="query" (ionChange)="showdata()">
 <ion-segment-button value="slide1">
TabTitle1
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button value="slide2">
 TabTitle2
</ion-segment-button>
<ion-segment-button value="slide3">
 TabTitle3
</ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment> 
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()">
<ion-slide>
Some Content
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
Some Content
</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>
Some Content
</ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Typescript code

```
 import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MainPage {

@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
public query : string = 'slide1';

showdata(){
  if(this.query == 'slide1')
  {
    this.slides.slideTo(0,0);
  }
  if(this.query == 'slide2')
  {       
    this.slides.slideTo(1,0);
  }
  if(this.query == 'slide3')
  {     
    this.slides.slideTo(2,0);
  }
}
  // showdata() function ends here !!!

slideChanged(){
    if(this.slides._activeIndex == 0){
        this.query = 'slide1';
    }
    if(this.slides._activeIndex == 1){
        this.query = 'slide2';
    }
    if(this.slides._activeIndex == 2){
        this.query = 'slide3';
    }

  }
```

CSS too:

```
.swiper-slide {
overflow-y: scroll;
display: block;
}
```